# jQuery event listener won't trip in code using setInterval() based Pomodoro timer

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having trouble tripping a jQuery event listener and I suspect that it has something to do with the behavior of the setInterval() based countdown timer I've implemented. Is the event listener not listening while the program is executing the setInterval function? Have I placed or implemented the listener incorrectly? Other jQuery functions on the page work, so I don't think that I have loaded jQuery incorrectly. I am certain that the jQuery selector matches the button I want to listen to.  I can't figure out why the listener won't trip, any suggestions are very much appreciated.

```
// Check the page has loaded jQuery
$(function () {

// Some variable used by session and break timers
var sessionLength = 25;
var breakLength = 5;
var inSession = true;
var onBreak = false;
var start;

// Listen for click on session length incrementer (wont enter code block on click)
$("#buttonS+").on("click", function () {
  console.log("got here");
  sessionLength++;
  $("#sessDur").text(sessionLength);
});

// Run timer if session hasn't been canceled (this works)
if (inSession === true) {
  start = new Date();
  var sessionTimer = window.setInterval(function () {
    var timeElapsed = (new Date() - start) / 1000;
    var minElapsed = Math.floor(timeElapsed / 60);
    var secElapsed = timeElapsed % ((1 + minElapsed) * 60);
    var minLeft = sessionLength - minElapsed;
    var secLeft = 60 - secElapsed;
    if (secLeft < 0) {
      secLeft = secLeft + (60 * minElapsed);
    }
    if (Math.round(secLeft) === 60) {
      $("#timeDisplay").text((minLeft + 1) + ":00");
    }
    else if (secLeft > 9) {
      $("#timeDisplay").text(minLeft + ":" + Math.round(secLeft));
    }
    else {
      $("#timeDisplay").text(minLeft + ":0" + Math.round(secLeft));
    }
    if(minElapsed === sessionLength + 1) {
      window.clearInterval(sessionTimer);
    }
  }, 1000);
  }

  // Run break timer if on break (not fully implemented/ tested)
  if (onBreak === true) {
    start = new Date();
    var breakTimer = window.setInterval(function () {
      var timeElapsed = (new Date() - start) / 1000;
      var minElapsed = Math.floor(timeElapsed / 60);
      var secElapsed = timeElapsed % ((1 + minElapsed) * 60);
      var minLeft = breakLength - minElapsed;
      var secLeft = 60 - secElapsed;
      if (secLeft < 0) {
        secLeft = secLeft + (60 * minElapsed);
      }
      if (Math.round(secLeft) === 60) {
        $("#timeDisplay").text((minLeft + 1) + ":00");
      }
      else if (secLeft > 9) {
        $("#timeDisplay").text(minLeft + ":" + Math.round(secLeft));
      }
      else {
        $("#timeDisplay").text(minLeft + ":0" + Math.round(secLeft));
      }
      if(minElapsed === breakLength + 1) {
        window.clearInterval(breakTimer);
      }
    }, 1000);
}
});
```

Comment: Are you adding #buttonS+ dynamically? It might not exist yet in the DOM when you are binding event listener.

Comment: Using a '+' sign in your id's is bad practice. They are usually used for 'selecting' neighbouring elements. Which is probably why the event isnt triggering.

Comment: It is also possible that you are effectively overwriting your binding event with some other add-on.  Consider making this JS file the last one applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, your code is correct. However, your id ("#buttonS+"), could be wrong. People don't normally put operators in identifiers.

Comment: Yup, totally works now. As you said, you shouldn't put operators in id's apparently. Thanks to everyone who responded, would have taken me forever to figure this one out.